# Back to previous revision of file in subversion

Tags: svn

How do I go back to the previous revision of a file in subversion? This might be the second most normal backward operation so it should be easy so why is it not documented clearly? I've already did revert and I need to go back even more. Now if I go back to a spec revision it's not the same as going back to the previous version of the file since just going back a revision might be some other revision than the last changes of that file and the file might be unchanged. Do you know what command I'm looking for?

Comment: Either the previous revision is the one you want, or it's not; backing out the changes since the previous revision should do exactly what you want.  If not, then either you are confused or you are not communicating the problem correctly.

Comment: Neither. We can't know that asking for revision 43 will bring the file to revision 25 if that was the previous. It seems this is how svn works and it is not possible to know this without info or test.

Comment: I see, so you want to revert a file to its state in the last revision where the file was changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you at `revision 2`, and you want to revert a file to `revision 1`.

**You do**
`svn merge -c -2 my.file`,
**OR**
`svn merge -r 43:4 my.file`

and then do `svn diff`, it seems to show one revision before **1** (that is, **0**);

Only when you do `svn merge -c 1 myfile (without the -)`, it looks like **myfile** is **reverted to rev 1**.

Comment: If I request for instance revision x then I get another revision of the file that is the previous version. This is not intuitive at all that asking for revision 43 might bring the file to revision 4.

Comment: you can do this `svn merge -r 43:4 my.file`

Comment: It's the default for my setup which is not possible to know. If I request a previous revision then of a file then I might get some totally other different revision of the file since the revision I'm asking about doesn't have a change of the file(???)

Answer (score 0):

1. **svn log [file]**: Check what the last revision against this file is.
2. **svn merge -c -NNNN [file]**: Take the changeset number from the log in step one & do a reverse merge, to revert the delta change of that revision.
3. **svn ci [file]**: Update the changes made locally to the repository so that the HEAD revision also removes the delta change